# How can I share common javascript to multiple portlets?

Tags: liferay-7

I have written javascript in one module or portlet, I want to use the same javascript into my other portlets or modules, How can I do that? any example.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add that JavaScript in theme. That is the best solution for this scenario.